# Consecutive threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Greetings,

I'm trying to solve the following task:
Given N threads, make them run consecutively. For example each of them should output it's number in the following order:

Thread 1 Thread 2 ... Thread N

How do I do this, using only wait/notify and synchronized methods (without flags, etc)?

P.S. Sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If not, why would you ever want to use threads to do this?

Comment: println is a lot faster when used concurrently :) ...sounds like homework though.

Comment: sounds like you want to implement a round robin scheduler

Answer (score 7):

```
thread1.start();
thread1.join();

thread2.start();
thread2.join();

...
```

The call to .join() will wait for the thread to complete before continuing.

Comment: +1, but you probably want a loop rather than thread1/thread2 etc. :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
thread1.run();
thread2.run();
thread3.run();
```

New threads are unnecessary unless concurrent execution is needed. A single thread can execute the Threads' bodies consecutively.

If this straightforward approach doesn't work (that is, satisfy a teacher's expectations for a contrived homework exercise), please clarify the problem in your question.

Comment: Doing just that, it's not guaranteed that it will print "Thread 1, Thread 2, Thread 3"

Comment: @(Alexander Pogrebnyak) Yes it will.

Comment: Alexander, he's calling .run(), not .start() :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [**join**ing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) the threads?

I will not providing more clues, as it is a homework.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code, it would look like this :

```
synchronized (var) 
{
  var.wait();
  print(var);
  var.notifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't edit each thread code. So here is is

```
...
final Thread[] Threads = ...;
Thread aSuperThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        for(Threads T : Threads)
            T.run();
    }
};
aSuperThread.start();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Executors?

```
// create ExecutorService to manage threads                        
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
threadExecutor.execute( task1 ); // start task1
threadExecutor.execute( task2 ); // start task2
threadExecutor.execute( task3 ); // start task3
```

Where task1, task2 and task3 are objects that implement the runnable interface.
Executors are available since Java 5
More info: http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20051126/JavaMultithreading_Tutorial_Part4.html